# How to integrate FB javascript API with my backend?

Tags: javascript, ajax, facebook, rest, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am using Facebooks javascript SDK, and I am able to login and do everything with it.

For backend I just have a simple rest api with database behind.

This is the call that gives me the status at the moment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus.

Question is, when login and status checking are done on my front end side, how does my backend know which user is logged in?

Yes I can just send the username to my REST endpoint, but since users can manipulate the ajax calls, this is quite unsafe. How should I be doing this in real world?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That depends what you want to do within your backend. If you actually want to make calls to the Graph API, you need to pass the Access Token generated during the Login process to your backend. The Access Token contains everything necessary to make calls for the specific user

E.g.

```
/me?fields={field_list}&access_token={access_token}
```

The `username` field is deprecated anyway.

Comment: Actually I just want the user to be authenticated on the backend, so that I know that this is the current user. For example, user logs in on the frontend side with FB JS SDK, and then I want to return all his "items" from the database to him. So I need to send somekind of identifier in the REST request that I know which user is currently logged in.

Comment: Then it doesn't really make sense to have him login via the JS SDK IMHO, because the auth happens in the frontend then... Why don't you use a backend SDK such as the PHP SDK?